# Data transfer from one object class to another with different format and properties name

Tags: c#, arrays, json, arraylist

I am stuck in a problem since more than a week. I am using C# and I am doing Zoho Integration with my application, and I am passing JSON string from my application to Middle layer which will call Zoho API and send required JSON format to insert records in zoho module.

I am sending JSON from my application is :

```
    {
  "TonerRequestID": 0,
  "CustAccountId": 0,
  "CRMAccountId": null,
  "CRMODId": null,
  "BillTo": "200173",
  "Asset": null,
  "AssetId": null,
  "CreatedDateTime": null,
  "CreatedIP": null,
  "CreatedBy": null,
  "ModifiedBy": null,
  "ModifiedIP": null,
  "ModifiedDateTime": null,
  "Remarks": "",
  "CurrStockQty": 0,
  "CurrReqQty": 0,
  "PrevColorCount": 0,
  "PrevBWCount": 0,
  "Attachment1": null,
  "Attachment1StoredPath": null,
  "Serial": "Manual Byepass MB-504         -VIKAS56789                    ",
  "SerialId": "371.0",
  "lsttonerRequestDetails": [
    {
      "TonerRequestID": "0",
      "CRMProductID": null,
      "AssetId": null,
      "ItemCode": "80636.0",
      "CurrStockQty": "4",
      "CreatedDateTime": null,
      "RequiredQty": "5",
      "PrevStockQty": "12",
      "PrevRequiredQty": "3",
      "dtLastReqDate": null
    },
    {
      "TonerRequestID": "0",
      "CRMProductID": null,
      "AssetId": null,
      "ItemCode": "80637.0",
      "CurrStockQty": "8",
      "CreatedDateTime": null,
      "RequiredQty": "9",
      "PrevStockQty": "6",
      "PrevRequiredQty": "7",
      "dtLastReqDate": null
    },
    {
      "TonerRequestID": "0",
      "CRMProductID": null,
      "AssetId": null,
      "ItemCode": "80638.0",
      "CurrStockQty": "12",
      "CreatedDateTime": null,
      "RequiredQty": "13",
      "PrevStockQty": "10",
      "PrevRequiredQty": "11",
      "dtLastReqDate": null
    },
    {
      "TonerRequestID": "0",
      "CRMProductID": null,
      "AssetId": null,
      "ItemCode": "80639.0",
      "CurrStockQty": "16",
      "CreatedDateTime": null,
      "RequiredQty": "17",
      "PrevStockQty": "14",
      "PrevRequiredQty": "15",
      "dtLastReqDate": null
    },
    {
      "TonerRequestID": "0",
      "CRMProductID": null,
      "AssetId": null,
      "ItemCode": "80640.0",
      "CurrStockQty": "20",
      "CreatedDateTime": null,
      "RequiredQty": "21",
      "PrevStockQty": "18",
      "PrevRequiredQty": "19",
      "dtLastReqDate": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to manipulate this JSON and create actual format which ZOHO module wants. i.e.

```
{    
    "data": [
        {
            "Layout": {
                "name" : "Toner",
                "id": "207069000003373769"
            },
            "Owner": {
                "id": "207069000001122001"
            },
            "Asset": {
                "id": "207069000025605299"
            },
            "Account_Name": {
                "id": "207069000019985406"
            },
            "Related_To": {
                "id": "207069000026124057"
            },
            "Contact": {
                "id": "207069000026124057"
            },
            "Current_Black_and_white_Count": "12",
            "Current_Color_Count": "12",
            "Current_Reading1": "12",
            "Current_Reading": "12",
            "Last_Spare_Request_Click_Count": "12",
            "Last_Spare_Request_Date": "2022-06-09",
            "Minimum_Yield": "12",
            "No_of_comments": "12",
            "Order_No": "12",
            "Previous_Reading": "12",
            "Previous_Reading1": "12",
            "Subject": "Azeem Test Details 2",
            "System_Yield": "12",
            "Current_Reading_Total": "12",
            "Previous_Reading_Total": "12",
            "Priority": "Medium",
            "Requested_Date_Time": "2022-06-17T18:00:00+05:30",
            "Solution": "Complex functionality",
            "Standard_Yield": "12",
            "Actual_Yield": "12",
            "Case_Origin": "12",
            "Status": "NEW",            
            "Toner_Request_Details": [{
            "Current_Stock1": "456",
            "Description": "456",
            "Item_Code1": {"id":"207069000024880067"},
            "Quantity_Req": "456"
            },
            {
            "Current_Stock1": "789",
            "Description": "789",
            "Item_Code1": {"id":"207069000024880067"},
            "Quantity_Req": "789"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make above Zoho JSON structure from JSON of my application which I put in start. As there are difference in every field name, I am using mapper table to map fields from both JSON. like :

[Image: Fields Mapping for both JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN2Rf.jpg)

So what I want to do is, I will loop through the source json fields and put a condition to match source JSON fields and Destination fields and if name matched I will assign value of source JSON field to Destination field.

I have defined a class to Deserialize source json and defined a class to put values in it and serialize to JSON and send to ZOHO.

Source Class :

```
public class TonerRequestMaster
{
    public Int64 TonerRequestID { get; set; }
    public Int64 CustAccountId { get; set; }
    public string CRMAccountId { get; set; }
    public string CRMODId { get; set; }
    public string BillTo { get; set; }
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatedIP { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedIP { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrStockQty { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrReqQty { get; set; }
    public decimal PrevColorCount { get; set; }
    public decimal PrevBWCount { get; set; }
    public string Attachment1 { get; set; }
    public string Attachment1StoredPath { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string SerialId { get; set; }
    public List<TonerRequestDetails> lsttonerRequestDetails { get; set; }
}
public class TonerRequestDetails
{
    public string TonerRequestID { get; set; }
    public string CRMProductID { get; set; }
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string CurrStockQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string RequiredQty { get; set; }
    public string PrevStockQty { get; set; }
    public string PrevRequiredQty { get; set; }
    public string dtLastReqDate { get; set; }
}
```

Destination Class :

```
{
    public class AccountName
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Asset
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public Layout Layout { get; set; }
        public Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public Asset Asset { get; set; }
        public AccountName Account_Name { get; set; }
        public RelatedTo Related_To { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public string Current_Black_and_white_Count { get; set; }
        public string Current_Color_Count { get; set; }
        public string Current_Reading1 { get; set; }
        public string Current_Reading { get; set; }
        public string Last_Spare_Request_Click_Count { get; set; }
        public string Last_Spare_Request_Date { get; set; }
        public string Minimum_Yield { get; set; }
        public string No_of_comments { get; set; }
        public string Order_No { get; set; }
        public string Previous_Reading { get; set; }
        public string Previous_Reading1 { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string System_Yield { get; set; }
        public string Current_Reading_Total { get; set; }
        public string Previous_Reading_Total { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime Requested_Date_Time { get; set; }
        public string Solution { get; set; }
        public string Standard_Yield { get; set; }
        public string Actual_Yield { get; set; }
        public string Case_Origin { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<TonerRequestDetail> Toner_Request_Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemCode1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Layout
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Owner
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelatedTo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class TonerRequestZoho
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class TonerRequestDetail
    {
        public string Current_Stock1 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ItemCode1 Item_Code1 { get; set; }
        public string Quantity_Req { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please help me in this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it would help if you created your c# models hierarchy like the JSON, and you have to make the models with same name as the JSON, for example:

```
public class Layout 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
public class Owner 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Zoho 
{
    public List<ZohoModel> Data { get; set; }
}
public class ZohoModel 
{
   public Layout Layout { get; set; }
   public Owner Owner { get; set; }
   public string Current_Black_and_white_Count { get; set; }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: I have edited my  question, please check. I am using class same as JSON but putting values from source JSON to destination class is spot where I am stuck.

Comment: you must first deserialize the source `JSON` to a c# model then map it to your destination model, then serialize the destination model. I think its the best way

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do what you have suggested. I have already deserialized the source JSON in a model and now want to map that model to destination model where fields are with different name. SO can you please guide how would I map them using any loop? You can see I have added both models in my question.

Comment: @AZEEMSHAIKH you can use the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000933/how-to-manually-mapping-dto-without-using-automapper